How to do a multi outputs regressiong using Keras Functional API and tf.Dataset without getting the error "Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor`"?
I want to build a neural network which will looks at an image and gives me 64 floats.
At first I had pandas data frames. The target frame looks like this (I have 64 number per images) :
       a1   a2   a3   a4   a5   a6   a7    a8    b1   b2  ...   h8
257  0.08  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.58  0.17  0.0  ...  0.58  
258  0.08  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.58  0.17  0.0  ...  0.58
259  0.08  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.58  0.17  0.0  ...  0.58  
260  0.08  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.58  0.17  0.0  ...  0.58 
261  0.08  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.5  0.58  0.17  0.0  ...  0.58  

The images frame looks like this :
257    chessred/images/2/G002_IMG000.jpg
258    chessred/images/2/G002_IMG001.jpg
259    chessred/images/2/G002_IMG002.jpg
260    chessred/images/2/G002_IMG003.jpg
261    chessred/images/2/G002_IMG004.jpg

I then make my tf.dataset
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images,train_target))

and map the images :
def read(image_path, position):
    #Load images
    file = tf.io.read_file(image_path) 
    #Convert image into numpy array
    file = tf.image.decode_image(file, channels=3, dtype=tf.float64, expand_animations = False) 
    #Resize images
    file = tf.image.resize(file, (224, 224)) 
    return file, position

train_dataset = train_dataset.map(read).shuffle(shuffle_num).batch(batch_size)

Then I build my neural network
pre_trained = tf.keras.applications.MobileNetV2(
    include_top=False, 
    weights='imagenet',
    input_shape=(image_size, image_size, 3)) 

pre_trained.trainable = False

#Add pooling layer and one dense layer
pre_trained_output = pre_trained.output
global_average_pooling2d = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(pre_trained_output)
intermediate = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='sigmoid')(global_average_pooling2d)

#Building 64 output layers 

a1  =   tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='a1', activation='sigmoid')(intermediate)
.
h8  =   tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, name='h8', activation='sigmoid')(intermediate)

I compile it
output_layers = [a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, 
             c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, d1, d2, d3, d4, d5, d6, d7, d8,
             e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7, e8, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8,
             g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, h7, h8]


model = tf.keras.Model(
    inputs=pre_trained.inputs,
    outputs=output_layers)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
    loss={"a1":"mse", "a2":"mse", "a3":"mse", "a4":"mse", "a5":"mse", "a6":"mse","a7":"mse", "a8":"mse",
         "b1":"mse", "b2":"mse", "b3":"mse", "b4":"mse", "b5":"mse", "b6":"mse","b7":"mse", "b8":"mse",
         "c1":"mse", "c2":"mse", "c3":"mse", "c4":"mse", "c5":"mse", "c6":"mse","c7":"mse", "c8":"mse",
         "d1":"mse", "d2":"mse", "d3":"mse", "d4":"mse", "d5":"mse", "d6":"mse","d7":"mse", "d8":"mse",
         "e1":"mse", "e2":"mse", "e3":"mse", "e4":"mse", "e5":"mse", "e6":"mse","e7":"mse", "e8":"mse",
         "f1":"mse", "f2":"mse", "f3":"mse", "f4":"mse", "f5":"mse", "f6":"mse","f7":"mse", "f8":"mse",
         "g1":"mse", "g2":"mse", "g3":"mse", "g4":"mse", "g5":"mse", "g6":"mse","g7":"mse", "g8":"mse",
         "h1":"mse", "h2":"mse", "h3":"mse", "h4":"mse", "h5":"mse", "h6":"mse","h7":"mse", "h8":"mse"},
    metrics={"a1":"accuracy", "a2":"accuracy", "a3":"accuracy", "a4":"accuracy", "a5":"accuracy", "a6":"accuracy","a7":"accuracy", "a8":"accuracy",
         "b1":"accuracy", "b2":"accuracy", "b3":"accuracy", "b4":"accuracy", "b5":"accuracy", "b6":"accuracy","b7":"accuracy", "b8":"accuracy",
         "c1":"accuracy", "c2":"accuracy", "c3":"accuracy", "c4":"accuracy", "c5":"accuracy", "c6":"accuracy","c7":"accuracy", "c8":"accuracy",
         "d1":"accuracy", "d2":"accuracy", "d3":"accuracy", "d4":"accuracy", "d5":"accuracy", "d6":"accuracy","d7":"accuracy", "d8":"accuracy",
         "e1":"accuracy", "e2":"accuracy", "e3":"accuracy", "e4":"accuracy", "e5":"accuracy", "e6":"accuracy","e7":"accuracy", "e8":"accuracy",
         "f1":"accuracy", "f2":"accuracy", "f3":"accuracy", "f4":"accuracy", "f5":"accuracy", "f6":"accuracy","f7":"accuracy", "f8":"accuracy",
         "g1":"accuracy", "g2":"accuracy", "g3":"accuracy", "g4":"accuracy", "g5":"accuracy", "g6":"accuracy","g7":"accuracy", "g8":"accuracy",
         "h1":"accuracy", "h2":"accuracy", "h3":"accuracy", "h4":"accuracy", "h5":"accuracy", "h6":"accuracy","h7":"accuracy", "h8":"accuracy"})

Finally I train it :
training = model.fit(train_dataset,
    epochs=epochs_num)

When I do I get this error :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/ChessRec/ChessRec.py", line 154, in <module>
    training = model.fit(train_dataset,
  File "/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/utils/traceback_utils.py", line 122, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/keras/src/trainers/compile_utils.py", line 561, in build
    for name, yt, yp in zip(output_names, y_true, y_pred):
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: Iterating over a symbolic `tf.Tensor` is not allowed. You can attempt the following resolutions to the problem: If you are running in Graph mode, use Eager execution mode or decorate this function with @tf.function. If you are using AutoGraph, you can try decorating this function with @tf.function. If that does not work, then you may be using an unsupported feature or your source code may not be visible to AutoGraph. See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/autograph/g3doc/reference/limitations.md#access-to-source-code for more information.

The shape of train_dataset seems to be correct. When I do train_dataset.take(1) I get <_TakeDataset element_spec=(TensorSpec(shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), TensorSpec(shape=(None, 64), dtype=tf.float64, name=None))>
Edit :
batch_size = 50

epochs_num = 2

shuffle_num = 6000

image_size = 224`enter code here`

Edit 2 :
I tried to make the dataset into numpy array
train_dataset = train_dataset.unbatch()
images = np.asarray(list(train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: x)))
labels = np.asarray(list(train_dataset.map(lambda x, y: y)))

before compiling and then training
training = model.fit(x=images, y=labels,
    epochs=epochs_num)

but the issue remains.
Edit 3 :
Using numpy array and specifying in fit which label correspond to which neuron (ie. 'a1':labels[:,0], 'a2':labels[:,1] , etc.), in the 'y' entry of fit() make it works. The use of tf.dataset is the issue.

Where do you specify the loss function for this model?

@xdurch0 I forget to post that part sorry. Just edited the post to add the compilation lines.

Check the shape of images & labels.

@twalow Using np.shape I get (1, 6000, 224, 224, 3) for images and (1, 6000, 64) for labels. 6000 images, 64 labels, 224x224 format and 3 channels. It looks ok to me.

What do you get when you do:
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.executing_eagerly())

@twalow It returns True

So I think the issue is you have a model with multiple outputs.
output_layers = [a1,....h8]
Since you're using more than one output Tensorflow uses dictionaries to match up the labels with the outputs. Each output layer should have a unique name that matches with your input labels.
labels_dict = {col: train_targets[col].values for col in train_targets.columns}
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((train_images, labels_dict))
train_dataset = train_dataset.map(read).shuffle(shuffle_num).batch(batch_size)

and remove your line:
train_dataset = train_dataset.unbatch()

As an extra I would suggest normalizing your image data too using:
file = tf.image.resize(file, (224, 224)) 
file = tf.cast(file, tf.float32) / 255.0 # add this line

Tensorflow does better with small numbers.
